# Can I include Facebook login/API calls *without* hosting my web application online?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having some trouble understanding the steps I need to take in order to make basic requests to the Facebook API. I've been reading the documentation, and having a play with the Graph Explorer, however I'm a little confused getting started.

I'm making a game application for a University submission, for which Facebook integration is a small but important part. I will be submitting this application on disk, and it will need to work when the HTML page is launched from this disk - this is where I'm getting a little stuck. I'm not sure if I'm overthinking this, but I seem to need to register as a Facebook Developer and set up an application domain. Is this necessary? I won't be able to host this application online, it will have to be submitted on disk.

So, my questions are -

- Is it possible to include basic Facebook integration **without** hosting the application online? (Login, retrieval of a list of the user's friend's `id`s)
- (If this is possible) what do I need to do to handle the basic 'setup' of Facebook integration? I've been looking at the [Javascript SDK reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and I see I need to have my **appId** and **channelUrl** for the Loading and Initialization. I see the appId quite clearly in the App Dashboard, however it is the channelURL I am having trouble with.

I hope that makes sense :)  Loading and initializing the framework and then making Graph API calls seems pretty straightforward - I'm just not sure if it's possible without hosting the application online.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your page should at least be reachable via HTTP – so put a portable webserver (could be a portable Apache distribution, or something smaller) on your “disk” as well, and run your app using `http://localhost/…`. Add that same address (protocol and domain only, no path) in your app settings for “Website with Facebook login”.

And for the `channelUrl`, see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/02/how-to--optimize-social-plugin-performance/